# What statistical test should I do for humpback whale singing behavior?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I am currently doing a study about the preference of humpback whales singing during night in the subarctic waters.

I have two variables in my data Existenceofsong (positive or negative detection; song and no song) and for the correspondent time each daylight regime (light, twilight or dark).

My sample size is 4382 and I'm using R program.

I would be very grateful if someone could give some tips with how should I have test my data and how to convert my variable so I can test them.

Here is the link to my data
https://ualg365-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/a67963_ualg_pt/ESZwU858KllDvR3PcPfNnuABaPBEPsbnXIIoWguIhusVVA?e=uE8Bq8

Comment: What do you want to test? If you are simply looking for an association between them, [Chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) test should work.

Comment: If there is a preference so sing in twlight and dark vs. light

Comment: What abou pair wise wilcoxon? is that good?

Comment: oops I think this one works https://ualg365-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/a67963_ualg_pt/ESZwU858KllDvR3PcPfNnuABaPBEPsbnXIIoWguIhusVVA?e=uE8Bq8

Comment: Your data can be summarized with a $2\times 3$ table of counts.  Begin by looking at it: often the results are so obvious they don't need a test to demonstrate them.

Comment: How large is your sample size? What software are you using to analyze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset is quite large (total n = 4382), so there might be other issues, like dependence ... but concentrating on your data, first, present is as an contingency table :

```
               ExistenceOfSong
daylight.regime nosong song
       dark        874  570
       light       847  323
       twilight   1216  552
```

As the numbers are large, a chisquared test is highly significant, but that is maybe not of much interest. Rather present the table with percentages of interest (left for you), or as a mosaicplot:

[image: mosaicplot of humpback songs]

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a contigency table as you suggested and I have the percentages per col and row. Thank you for the graph as well. I was wondering if you have any suggestion regarding the tests to prove if there is significant difference, I tried an ANOVA but I think it doesn't fit with the data, what do you think about wilcoxon? To test twilight and dark against light. Thank you very much again, it helped me a lot!

Comment: For the contingency table, use the chisquared test! Wilcox test needs ordered data, which you do not have. If you need to include other covariates (it seems you have some), logistic regression.

Comment: Ok, thank you! One more thing that I'm not sure. What does the p value of a chi squared test tell in this case? If it is highly significant, what is my null hypothesis for this test?

Comment: The null hypothesis of the chisquared test is independence (or homogeneity, that is, equal row probabilities---the test is the same). A low p-value means that is rejected, but with your sample size, you will reject with small deviations from the null.